# ReferenceError: HideShow is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference

HTML :

```
<select class="required-entry" id="customer" name="customer">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="new">Add New Customer</option>
 </select>
```

Javascript  :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $('customer').observe("change",function(event){
      var sourceElement = Event.findElement(event);
      HideShow(sourceElement);
  });

 function HideShow(sourceElement)
 {
     console.log('come in this function');
 }
</script>
```

I am getting above error while change option.

Please help me.. I already check many reference but doesn't help.

Comment: What library/function exactly is `$.observe`…?

Comment: At first you have wrong selector for select#customer
$('customer') instead $('#customer')

Comment: Is this really how your code looks, or do you have function definitions nested inside other functions?

Comment: Are you using `prototype.js`?

Comment: @Barmar I am calling same function from other events also..

Comment: That doesn't answer my question? I suspect the problem is with function scope, you have to make sure the function definition is in the same scope as the caller.

Comment: I would do it like this: 
`
$('#customer').on("change",function(event) {
      HideShow(this);
});

 function HideShow(sourceElement)
 {
     console.log('come in this function');
 }`

Comment: @vothaison   if I want to pass more arguments then ?

Comment: More arguments to what? HideShow() ?

Comment: @vothaison yes in HideShow()

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try to define function like:

```
HideShow = function(sourceElement)
 {
     console.log('come in this function');
 }
```

Comment: Why is this better?

Comment: This will make the problem even bigger...

Comment: it is working for me

Comment: The difference is that 
 function HideShow(sourceElement) is a function expression and so only defined when that line is reached, whereas 
 HideShow = function(sourceElement) is a function declaration and is defined as soon as its surrounding function or script is executed.

Comment: It's exactly the opposite.

Comment: Hey 'Jonas w' how will this cause bigger problem?

Comment: @BhargavJoshi Functions defined with `function HideShow(sourceElement)` are hoisted to the top of the scope, so they're available immediately. But it doesn't make a difference in this case, because the function isn't called until the event occurs, which is after either type of definition is reached.

Comment: As deceze told its the other way round...

Comment: It may work because of the typo the OP made in not shown parts...

Comment: function declaration(){} vs. expression=function(){} ...